# Migrate from ASP.NET Core Identity to Keycloak

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, keycloak

So, I already have a table of users with hashed passwords using ASP.NET Core Identity and want to migrate them to my Keycloak database.

Is there any way of doing this?